# Cassandra BoundStatement with Range Boundary Query

Tags: java, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am using PreparedStatement and boundStatment to execute some Cassandra queries. I am trying to execute the range query. This is the query I want to create:

```
getAllRecordsOnIndexRange = getSession.prepare(QueryBuilder.select(documentId, documentName, documentIndex)
          .from(tableName)               
          .where(QueryBuilder.eq(documentId,QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
          .and(QueryBuilder.gte(documentIndex, QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
          .and(QueryBuilder.lte(documentIndex, QueryBuilder.bindMarker())));
```

**'documentId'** is partition key and **'documentIndex'** is clustering key. I want to have range query on column documentIndex like "get me all records with given documentId and documentIndex >= 3 and documentIndex <= 10"

When I want to run the query, I call

```
public Statement buildGetAllRecordsOnIndexRange(int documentId, String documentName, int startDocumentIndex, int endDocumentIndex)
{
    BoundStatement boundStatement = getAllRecordsOnIndexRange
            .bind()
            .setString(DOCUMENT_ID, documentId)
            //how to set start and end documentIndex
    databaseManager.applyReadStatementsConfiguration(boundStatement);
    return boundStatement;
}
```

How can I set the startDocumentIndex and endDocumentIndex for the above query?

Comment: Is your column "documentIndex" a clustering column?

Comment: Yes 'documentIndex' is clustering column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [named bind markers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/statements/built/#prepared-statements) instead of unnamed - it's much easier to read code that use them.   So in your case the code will look as following:

```
PreparedStatement pStatement = session.prepare(QueryBuilder.select(documentId, documentName, documentIndex)
      .from(tableName)               
      .where(QueryBuilder.eq(documentId,QueryBuilder.bindMarker("documentId")))
      .and(QueryBuilder.gte(documentIndex, QueryBuilder.bindMarker("documentIndexStart")))
      .and(QueryBuilder.lte(documentIndex, QueryBuilder.bindMarker("documentIndexEnd"))));
```

And then you can bind the by name:

```
BoundStatement stmt = pStatement.bind()
       .setString("documentId", startDocumentIndex)
       .setInt("documentIndexStart", startDocumentIndex)
       .setInt("documentIndexEnd", endDocumentIndex);
```